# XML comments and Delphi XMl Data Binding

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-xe

Have anybody had a isse with comments `<!--´comment -->` and XML data binding in delphi. Im tryng to load the xml with the wizard but im getting error. XML looks like this:

```
<!-- For more info go: https://www.energia.ee/et/home/electricity/rates -->
<settings>
    <!-- Electrical energy basic rate (Elektrienergia põhitariif) -->
    <electrical_basic_rate>3.19</electrical_basic_rate>
    <!-- Network service basic rate (Võrguteenuse põhitariif) -->
    <network_service_basic_rate>4.13</network_service_basic_rate>
    <!-- Renewable energy charge (Taastuvenergia tasu) -->
    <renewable_energy_charge>0.61</renewable_energy_charge>
    <!-- Electricity excise tax (Elektriaktsiis) -->
    <electricity_excise_tax>0.447</electricity_excise_tax>
</settings>
```

I get error on the 3-d line. Error message looks like this:

[image]

Strange is that the first comment is not giving a error. Looks like a Delphi XE bug to me..

Comment: Are you sure the comments are the problem? Try removing the non-ASCII characters and see whether you still get the error. What encoding does your file use?

Comment: Ah, you are right. Why didnt i think of that myself (:
Please add it as a answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually broken because of this `õ` character, I changed them all to `o` and it worked.

I added `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` the converted the file from ANSI to UTF-8
and it worked as expected, with the `õ` character.

It also works with out the encoding line if you use a UTF-8 Encoding instead of ANSI